# How to create a custom bind to get a callback each time each-* routine creates/destroys a view?

Tags: data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding, rivets.js

[RivetJS](http://rivetsjs.com/) is fantastic! Thank you for making it agnostic!

This is a crucial feature I need for [*flow*](https://github.com/flow-stack/flow) and I'm struggling to get it done using [RivetJS](http://rivetsjs.com/).

The most I could do so far was to get the element that later on is going to be cloned using something like this:

```
var theEachBind = rivets.binders['each-*'].bind;

      rivets.binders['each-*'].bind = function(el){
        console.info(this);
        theEachBind.call(this,el);
      };
```

Instead of the `console.info` there, I could manipulate the Binder but that's not really going to help me to get this done I think. Or I might be missing something?

What would be the plan to get a callback at the moment [each-*] creates and destroys views?

For me a callback would be ideal so I could make the controller cleanly maintain its subviews and subcrontrollers. Would this need a feature request in Rivets.js?

Answer (score 0):

a callback on bind has been requested, but is not in there at the moment
https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/337#issuecomment-59629266

Comment: Thanks @Symeon, that one will be handy too.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the feature is not present in RivetJS. But there are discussions about making it and hopefully we get there.

For getting this done today, what I did was use a modified version of rivets. What I've changed was the routine on the `each-*` binder.

I've wanted two callbacks, one on creation and one on destruction of the views. I've also needed tho have the instance of the model for each specific view.

Below is the full routine for the `each-*` that I'm using. My two lines of code are commented with a label like this `// sas:`

You'll be able to use those callbacks by using the version of `routine` I'm sharing here plus a custom binder like this:

```
rivets.binders['iterated-*'] = rivets.binders['each-*];
var theEachBind = rivets.binders['each-*'].bind;
var theEachRoutine = rivets.binders['each-*'].routine;

rivets.binders['iterated-*'].bind = function(el){
    this.view.onViewCreated = function(aView, aModel){ self._onViewCreated_for_(aView, aModel) };
    this.view.onViewDestroyed = function(aView, aModel){ self._onViewDestroyed_for_(aView, aModel)};
    theEachBind.call(this,el);
};
```

As bonus, this is how you get a callback for every time routine evaluates:

```
rivets.binders['iterated-*'].routine = function(el, collection){
    var results = theEachRoutine.call(this, el, collection);
    self._onRoutine_value_(el, collection);
    return results;
```

With that you'll get called back on:

1. `_onViewCreated_for_(aView, aModel)`
2. `_onViewDestroyed_for_(aView, aModel)`
3. `_onRoutine_value_(el, collection)`

That's how I use it for [flow](https://github.com/flow-stack/flow)'s IteratedControllers and they maintain creation and destruction of **arbitrarily complex** children.

Finally here is the custom rivetjs code that makes this possible:

```
routine: function(el, collection) {
  var binding, data, i, index, k, key, model, modelName, options, previous, template, v, view, _i, _j, _k, _len, _len1, _len2, _ref1, _ref2, _ref3, _ref4, _results;
  modelName = this.args[0];
  collection = collection || [];
  if (this.iterated.length > collection.length) {
    _ref1 = Array(this.iterated.length - collection.length);
    for (_i = 0, _len = _ref1.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      i = _ref1[_i];
      view = this.iterated.pop();
      view.unbind();

      // sas: this one is for the view destroy callback
      if(this.view.onViewDestroyed){this.view.onViewDestroyed(view, view.models[modelName])};

      this.marker.parentNode.removeChild(view.els[0]);
    }
  }
  for (index = _j = 0, _len1 = collection.length; _j < _len1; index = ++_j) {
    model = collection[index];
    data = {
      index: index
    };
    data[modelName] = model;
    if (this.iterated[index] == null) {
      _ref2 = this.view.models;
      for (key in _ref2) {
        model = _ref2[key];
        if (data[key] == null) {
          data[key] = model;
        }
      }
      previous = this.iterated.length ? this.iterated[this.iterated.length - 1].els[0] : this.marker;
      options = {
        binders: this.view.options.binders,
        formatters: this.view.options.formatters,
        adapters: this.view.options.adapters,
        config: {}
      };
      _ref3 = this.view.options.config;
      for (k in _ref3) {
        v = _ref3[k];
        options.config[k] = v;
      }
      options.config.preloadData = true;
      template = el.cloneNode(true);
      view = new Rivets.View(template, data, options);
      view.bind();

      // sas: this is for the create callback
      if(this.view.onViewCreated){this.view.onViewCreated(view, data[modelName])};

      this.iterated.push(view);
      this.marker.parentNode.insertBefore(template, previous.nextSibling);
    } else if (this.iterated[index].models[modelName] !== model) {
      this.iterated[index].update(data);
    }
  }
  if (el.nodeName === 'OPTION') {
    _ref4 = this.view.bindings;
    _results = [];
    for (_k = 0, _len2 = _ref4.length; _k < _len2; _k++) {
      binding = _ref4[_k];
      if (binding.el === this.marker.parentNode && binding.type === 'value') {
        _results.push(binding.sync());
      } else {
        _results.push(void 0);
      }
    }
    return _results;
  }
},
```

PS: What would make me happy is to be able to deprecate `iterated-*` and see those callbacks as regular features of `each-*`